# PK not found while saving collection of entities (bug ??)

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

i have ORA-02291 while creating new object (entitymanager.persist(taskVisit))

```
@Entity(name = "CRM_TASKDEPARTURE")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = TaskType.Consts.VISIT_ID)
public class TaskVisit extends Task {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<TaskVisitAddress> addresses = new ArrayList();

public TaskVisit() { }


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy = "taskVisit")
public List<TaskVisitAddress> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
 }
}
```

Connstraint is CRM_TaskVisitAddress(TASKID)

Code of entity:

```
@Entity(name = "CRM_TaskDepartureAddress")
public class TaskVisitAddress implements Serializable {
...any fields 
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TASKID")
public TaskVisit getTaskVisit() {
    return taskVisit;
 }
@Id
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSONADDRESSID")
public PersonAddress getPersonAddress() {
    return personAddress;
}
}
```

Exception:

Error Code: 2291
Call: INSERT INTO CRM_TASKDEPARTUREADDRESS (TASKID, PERSONADDRESSID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [3299, 1]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (DUMMY.FK_CRM_TASKDEPARTUREADDR_TASKI) violated -  parent key not found

Where is the mistake? 
P.s. in test object saved without exception...

**Updated**
I found wrong INSERT generated sequence
1. insert into superclass Task (right)
2. insert into CRM_TaskDepartureAddress (wrong)
3. insert into CRM_TASKDEPARTURE (wrong)
№ 2 and 3 must be swaped, becouse CRM_TaskDepartureAddress referenced to CRM_TASKDEPARTURE .
**Updated**
InheritanceType.JOINED

Comment: why not share the full exception, stack trace, and what "ORA-blahblah" means?

Comment: Is this a single table or joined table inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a ManyToOne as your primary key; it is stating that there are many TaskVisitAddress instances referencing the same TaskVisit, while your @Id requires something that is unique.

You need to find something on your TaskVisitAddress that will uniquely identify it from other TaskVisitAddress instances, such as Integer id assigned through sequencing.

The `@JoinColumn(name = "TASKID")` is referring to "TASKID" in the Task table, as JPA only allows relationships to reference an Entity's primary key, making the constraint requiring CRM_TASKDEPARTURE to be inserted first is incorrect.  If you must keep the constraint and require CRM_TASKDEPARTURE to be inserted first, you can try specifying the table name in the joinColumn:

```
  @JoinColumn(name = "TASKID", referencedColumnName = "CRM_TASKDEPARTURE.TASKID")
```

as described in feature request
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333100

Comment: TaskVisitAddress  have composite id

Comment: Helps to show it.  Is there another TaskVisitAddress with that same composite PK?  If so either you haven't updated the composite value correctly, or you should be merging your entity in instead of calling persist.  Persist is only for new entity instances, and is expected to throw an exception if it already exists

Comment: my problem only with new object

Comment: JPA only allows referencing an Entity's primary key, and in this case, the primary key is within the Task table.  Everything references a Task subclass should use the Task ID, so the CRM_TaskDepartureAddress's constraint (and foreign key) should reference the correctly inserted Task row, not the CRM_TASKDEPARTURE table.

Comment: @Chis expect Task class has 5 sublaasses and problem only with TaskDeparture =(

Comment: If this is the issue, the commit order is determined by relationship processing, so those other entities might have different relationships or get calculated slightly differently. You haven't shown your complete model, but it likely has some reason to think CRM_TaskDepartureAddress should be inserted before entries in CRM_TASKDEPARTURE. As JPA doesn't allow non-pk references, it has no way of knowing of the CRM_TaskDepartureAddress -> CRM_TASKDEPARTURE reference in your current model. There are ways to tell it you might try if you need to, but they are not generic JPA

Comment: thanks a lot for your help,i will try to do it by tomorrow

Comment: "@JoinColumn(name = "CRM_TASKDEPARTURE.TASKID")" generic Call: INSERT INTO CRM_TASKDEPARTUREADDRESS (**CRM_TASKDEPARTURE.TASKID**, PERSONADDRESSID) VALUES (?, ?)

Comment: I forgot about the table component within JoinColumn.  Try that instead.

Comment: Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [CRM_TASKDEPARTURE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(by.softclub.sccrm.task.data.TaskVisitAddress --> [DatabaseTable(CRM_TASKDEPARTUREADDRESS)])

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the java doc.  It is the referencedColumnName that is used to tell JPA which field to reference, and you want to point that at the "CRM_TASKDEPARTURE.TASKID" field.  Keep name="TASKID" or what ever you want your foreign key field to be.

Comment: you mean - in CRM_TASKDEPARTURE change "mappedBy" to @JoinColumn("TASKID") and in CRM_TASKDEPARTUREADDRESS improve @JOINCOLUMN(name="TASKID") to @JOINCOLUMN(name="TASKID",table="CRAM_TASKDEPARTURE",referenceJoinColumn = @JoinColumn(name="TASKID") ?

Comment: no, just the join column on the ManyToOne mapping needs to change.  If you add a join column on the ManyToOne, you'll have the same issue, and require the same changes to the join column so that it points to the CRAM_TASKDEPARTURE field instead of Task table's field, but you'll have issues with having two mappings to set the same foreign key.